# Stop sound when deleting files (or system events)

Tags: indicator-sound

Ubuntu Mate 18.04

I am trying to shut off that sound that occurs when I delete files.

I tried this.

```
Open dconf-editor. Browse to
org/gnome/desktop/sound
On the right, unclick event-sounds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound Preferences
Set alert volume to mute.